# android module fails transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForSigned FAILED

Tags: android, proguard

I have an android project that compiles fine in android studio. I wanted to build a signed apk and decided to do it the command-line way. So I updated the build.gradle file like this. I then issue a command on the command line from the project directory

gradlew assembleSigned

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        signed {
            storeFile file('mykeystore.keystore')
            storePassword 'passhere'
            keyAlias 'myalias'
            keyPassword 'keypass'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        signed {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.signed
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':myapplibrary')
}
```

I does compiling etc and then ends up with these errors. In the end it says

:myappmodule:android module fails transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForSgined FAILED

[image]
[image]